# Dgrid grouping based on checkbox and grid values

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dstore

I am wondering how to use dgrid so that I can get a structure like in attached image. I am using dgrid, dstore and dojo 1.10 .

[image]
[image]
I need to create folder type structure when I check the checkbox or any structure which is supported by dgrid. Any help how to proceed further would be great and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using a the dgrid tree plugin? There's quite a bit of useful information [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.15/doc/components/column-plugins/tree.md) and some examples [here](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Tree_expand.html) and [here](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Tree.html).

What you're trying to achieve seems like it should be possible with just using the regular tree plugin but I could be misinterpreting your question. Correct me if I've missed anything

Comment: @Richard- Thanks for the reply. I am not sure how to arrange my store so that I can get tree structure like second diagram on check box checked.

Comment: What does your store look like? And potentially you'll just have to overwrite or write your own getChildren function in your store. Like getChildren: function(object) { //do something }